# Foolproofing a Python calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, calculator

I'm writing a basic calculator which works with two different numbers.
So far, I managed to write a working prototype, but while dividing and foolproofing it I ran into a multitude of problems, so I'm posting them 
separately.

---

I want the program to repeat the question if the user doesn't provide an eligible operator. That's the code I have now:

```
def optn_query():
    print("Hulk can different things with number!")
    print("YOU!")
    optn = input("What Hulk do with number?! ")
    return optn
```

**Do I use an if statement to determine if the input is correct?**

---

Also I put return optn in there so the next function (gracefully called hulk_math) wouldn't fail midway, but it still does:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hulc.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "hulc.py", line 13, in main
    hulk_math()
  File "hulc.py", line 41, in hulk_math
    if optn == "+":
NameError: name 'optn' is not defined
```

What should I do to fix this?

Here's hulk_math() itself:

```
def hulk_math():
    if optn == "+":
        result = num1 + num2
        print("Hulk ADDS!!! Hulk thinks it's {0}!".format(result))
    elif optn == "-":
        result = num1 - num2
        print("Hulk SUBTRACTS!!! Hulk thinks it's {0}!".format(result))
    elif optn == "*":
        result = num1 * num2
        print("Hulk MULTIPLIES!!! Hulk thinks it's {0}!".format(result))
    elif optn == "/":
        result = num1 / num2
        print("Hulk DIVIDES!!! Hulk thinks it's {0}!".format(result))
    main()
```

Comment: You may want to learn/understand the basics before you write any programs, were did you think `optn` was going to come from? Also you may find a while loop useful and a return can end a function, no need for sys.exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call your function:

```
def hulk_math():
    optn = optn_query()
    #The rest of your code
```

Also, unless `num1` and `num2` are defined elsewhere in your code such that they are in the scope of `hulk_math`, your program is going to fail there too.

Comment: They are, and moreover they are defined in the same way optn is.

Comment: I call the optn_query() function in main() - when I call it in hulk_math() it loops forever calling different other functions of the code. It's actually reaaally weird.

Comment: Why don't you post `main` too?  It sounds like a weird setup.  Keep in mind that if `optn` has a value in `main`, that value does not get passed into `hulk_math` unless you do it explicitly.  `hulk_math` should probably be something like  `def hulk_math(num1, optn, num2)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `global` isn't the right way to do this.  Pass values from one function to another by saving their return values and passing them as arguments.

```
def main():
    intro()
    num1 = num1_query()
    optn = optn_query()
    num2 = num2_query()
    hulk_math(num1, optn, num2)

def hulk_math(num1, optn, num2):
    #Your original code will work as expected
```

Comment: You are of course right, I was then learning Python as my first language and didn't know how to use arguments. At all.
I'm writing this comment so nobody will follow my example and use globals.